# PHP shuffled token not displaying with email entered and button selected

Tags: php, mysql

Using a form that has a user submit his/her email and a php query of the database, I am hoping to generate a shuffled token, however, upon button click, the token is not displaying on the page. I have checked the connection to the database and it is successful. Code is as follows:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "admin";
$password = "";
$database = "registration";

    if (isset($_POST["forgotPass"])) {
        $connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

        $email = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);

        $data = $connection->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email'");

        if ($data->num_rows > 0) {
            $str = "0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
            $str = str_shuffle($str);
            $str = substr($str, 0, 10);

            echo $str;
        } else {
            echo "Please check your inputs!";
        }
    }
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <form action="forgotpassword.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address..."><br>
            <input type="button" name="forgotPass" value="Request Password" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any and all help/suggestions.

Comment: Well you aren't putting any text into the body of your (very partial) HTML code, for starters.

Comment: Are you sure that forgotPass is set in $_POST? Also can you just check if $_POST is set since it looks like whenever that form is submitted it should do that action anyway?

Comment: And yeah, It might be easier to spot if you move the echo $str into the html output.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Comment: @tadman, thanks for the warnings. i was not aware of Laravel. I will give that a look. thanks again for the insight.